# How to use SELECT DISTINCT and CONCAT in the same SQL statement

Tags: sql, select, distinct, concatenation

So I am feeding the results of this SQL into an array.  The array later becomes the suggestions for a textbox that operates while typing.  I want it to only return each name 1 time, even if the person has multiple appointments.  Currently, this returns all appointments for the person with that name, so if "Brad Robins" has 5 appointments, and I start to type "Brad", it displays "Brad Robins" 5 times in the suggestions instead of only once.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(clients.studentFirstName, ' ', clients.studentLastName) AS name, appointments.location, appointments.subLocation, appointments.appointmentAddress1, appointments.appointmentAddress2, appointments.appointmentCity, appointments.appointmentState, appointments.appointmentZip, appointments.startTime, appointments.endTime, appointments.date, clients.school
                    FROM appointments JOIN clients
                    ON appointments.clientID = clients.clientID
                    WHERE CONCAT(clients.studentFirstName, ' ', clients.studentLastName) = '".$roommate."' AND clients.school = '".$school."';";
```

To me, it just seems like DISTINCT and CONCAT aren't playing nicely together.

Comment: If the only purpose of this query is to return a list of names to suggest to the user, and you're not actually using the appointments table in the final output to your program... why are you joining to it in the first place?

Comment: I use the other info later, but it was easy enough to separate it and do two queries, leaving only name in the first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Distinct goes against the entire row of ALL columns, not just the name portion... So if the appointments are on different date/times, locations, etc, they will all come out.  If all you want to show is the NAME portion, strip the rest of the other content.  Query the available appointments AFTER a person has been chosen.

Answer (score 6):

The problem are the other fields; DISTINCT applies to the whole result. Probably the best thing is to do to separate queries or populate 2 different arrays; if you ORDER BY name, you can remove duplicates by copying into the dest array only when the name changes.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use DISTINCT, use group by:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(clients.studentFirstName, ' ', clients.studentLastName) AS name, appointments.location, appointments.subLocation, appointments.appointmentAddress1, appointments.appointmentAddress2, appointments.appointmentCity, appointments.appointmentState, appointments.appointmentZip, appointments.startTime, appointments.endTime, appointments.date, clients.school
                FROM appointments JOIN clients
                ON appointments.clientID = clients.clientID
                WHERE CONCAT(clients.studentFirstName, ' ', clients.studentLastName) = '".$roommate."' AND clients.school = '".$school."' group by CONCAT(clients.studentFirstName, ' ', clients.studentLastName);";
```

Also be careful about XSS in $school and $roomate if this accessible outside.

Comment: very nice solution!  I have already switched it to two queries based on the first two answers, but I will certainly remember this for next time!

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
group by name
```

at the end, which would cause the query to return only one of each name, but then you can't predict what appointment results will be returned in cases where a client has multiple appointments, and the query stops being very useful.

Like others have pointed out, you should probably just get the list of appointments after the client has been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

```
select colA||' - '||colB
from table1
where colA like 'beer%'
group by colA||' - '||colB
order by colA||' - '||colB
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT MD5(CONCAT(clients.studentFirstName, ' ', clients.studentLastName)) as id, appointments.location, appointments.subLocation, ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Select distinct concat(....)
From ....

Comment: It doesn't seem much different from the author's question. It would be better if you clarify what's wrong with the author's code